# perl Find varying element id using HTML::Treebuilder

Tags: javascript, perl, xpath, html-treebuilder

I am trying to use a websites in built search function to collect data from it but can't work out how to press the 'search' button as it has some javascript wrapped around it and the id changes with each new iteration of the page.

Data for the section of the site is as below.

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <td>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <!-- start of toolbar Main -->
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <table>
            <tr class="buttonPad">
            </tr>
            <tr>
   *          <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="button"><a id="S7674" accesskey="S" class="button" title="SEARCH" onclick="dispatch('S7674');"><u>S</u>></td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
          <td</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

and my code

```
   my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
      $tree->parse($url);

   my @nodes = $tree->findnodes('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table.buttonSpace/tbosy/tr/a.button')->get_nodelist; # line is modified later.
   my $nodecount = scalar(@nodes);

   if ($nodecount > 0 ) { print "we found something\n"; }
   else { print "nothing found\n"; } 

   foreach my $node (@nodes)
   {
      print "node is $node\n";
      my $id = $node->findvalue('button');
      print "my id is $id\n";
   }
```

Sadly my code doesn't return any node values.

Many thanks in advance.

Micro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Data::Dumper;

my $html = <<HTML;
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <td>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <!-- start of toolbar Main -->
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <table>
            <tr class="buttonPad">
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="button"><a id="S7674" accesskey="S" class="button" title="SEARCH" onclick="dispatch('S7674');"><u>S</u>></td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
          <td</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
HTML

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $html );
foreach my $atag ( $tree->look_down( _tag => q{a}, 'class' => 'button', 'title' => 'SEARCH' ) ) {
    print Dumper $atag->attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, This seems to work nicely on this HTML data but not when I try it on the website itself. (Note, I tided this data a lot  for this post) Is there something I should do to the url data before running this?

Comment: and how would I assign the 'id' to a variable to allow me to call it as a button click later?

Comment: Post the unaltered html. You might find something like this much easier to use for your purposes: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of the post? 
I have very little experience with python, so I suspect it'll be even more painful.

Comment: Example one on that page is a good place to start. `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo!' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()`

Comment: Ah, I should have been a bit clearer. I'm trying to use perl for this. I don't really want to move over to python.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try a simpler XPath query. You don't need to have the whole hierarchy there, that's overkill. And hard to get right: your HTML doesn't include the `tbody` that you have in your query (nor the `tbosy` that you also have ;--).

Try this if the way you identify the element is through the button class and title:

```
$tree->findnodes( '//td[@class="button"]/a[@class="button" and @title="SEARCH"]')
```